# Issues with an discord.py Mass-Ban Command if the User is Banned

Tags: discord.py

[image]

If the User is already banned, the bot shall add 1 to the failed variable... However the failed variable always returns 0 even though a user is banned from the guild

Here's the code:

```py
    @commands.command(aliases = ["multiban" , "mass-ban" , "multi-ban"])
    @commands.bot_has_permissions(ban_members = True)
    @commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
    async def massban(self , ctx , targets: commands.Greedy[discord.User] , * , grund="Kein Grund angegeben"):
        with ctx.channel.typing():
            banlist = await ctx.guild.bans()
            banned = 0
            days = 0
            tries = 0
            failed = 0
            developer = self.client.get_user(705557092802625576)
            if developer in targets:
                failed += 1
                banned -= 1
            else:
                for x in targets:
                    tries += 1
                    if x in banlist:
                        failed += 1
                        banned -= 1
                    else:
                        try:
                            await ctx.guild.ban(x , reason = f"{grund}" , delete_message_days = days)
                            banned += 1
                        except Exception as e:
                            failed += 1
                            print(e)
                embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff2200 , title = "Massban ausgeführt :tools:" ,
                                      description = f"Es wurde versucht, **{tries}** Personen zu bannen. Ergebnisse: \n**{banned}** Nutzer wurde/n gebannt. \n**{failed}** Nutzer konnte/n nicht gebannt werden.")
                embed.set_footer(text = f"User-ID: {ctx.author.id}" , icon_url = f"{ctx.message.author.avatar_url}")
                embed.set_author(name = f"{ctx.author}" , icon_url = f"{ctx.message.author.avatar_url}")
                return await ctx.reply(embed = embed , mention_author = False)

    @massban.error
    async def massban_error(self , ctx , error):
        if isinstance(error , commands.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Berechtigungs-Fehler! [Gebrauchte Berechtigung: ban_members]")
        elif isinstance(error , commands.BotMissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Berechtigungs-Fehler! [Gebrauchte Berechtigung: ban_members]")
        elif isinstance(error , commands.UserNotFound):
            pass
        else:
            failed += 1
            raise error
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be this line here.

```py
developer = 705557092802625576
if developer in targets:
    failed += 1
    banned -= 1
```

You are checking if an `int` is in a list of `discord.User` objects which will always return false. You should instead do `developer = self.bot.fetch_user(705557092802625576)`.

Comment: Alright, I got it working as intented, thanks for the fast response and support! :D

Comment: You can accept my answer if it helped. :)

Comment: you should always try to avoid api calls. use get_user instead of fetch_user.

Comment: Yea but sometimes the user might not be cached in the bot's memory. It is better to create a instance variable (I think thats what they are called) and get the user once when the cog is initalized. Basically `self.developer = bot.fetch_user(id)` (not tested if it actually works btw)

Comment: I got a new Problem:

If the User is already banned, the bot shall add 1 to the failed variable... However the failed variable always returns 0 even though a user is banned from the guild